# Does an ancestor index consume less storage? About how much less storage would it consume?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Given the fact that indices in app engine occupy significant amounts of storage, I was wondering which setup would save me more storage. I have an ndb model that has more than 100,000 entities. The autogenerated index entries for it in index.yaml are the following:

```
# index.yaml
indexes:
- kind: MyModel
  properties:
  - name: label
  - name: date

- kind: MyModel
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: label
  - name: date
```

I was wondering if keeping both indexes would not significantly impact the amount of storage they use. Or would I be able to save around 50% of the storage they consume by removing one of them? As of now, I can much easily refactor my code to use or not use ancestor queries, so refactoring code is not an issue.  I am solely interested in knowing which path would save me more storage.

And if its best to remove one of them, which should I remove that would save me more storage? The index for ancestor queries, or the one that isn't?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You only need one of them. And you need the ancestor if you need consistency (for transactions).

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep the index with `ancestor: yes` and delete the other one. Although I would still like to know how much memory I lose/save by having `ancestor: yes` on an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use autogenerated indexes (index.yaml has 2 modes: auto and manual), and first worked with no ancestors, but later changed your scheme (so new index was automatically added), you should remove first index:

```
# index.yaml
- kind: MyModel
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: label
  - name: date
```

If you create and use entities with no ancestor it is supposed to be None and this index works well. I advice you to take manual control over indexes if you worried about space/speed issues.

Comment: You described my situation exactly. The indices are both autogenerated and I started with queries that don't use ancestors. Thanks for the answer. I'll keep the index with `ancestor: yes` for strong consistency as suggested by @voscausa, and delete the other one. Although I am still curious as to what the approximate storage difference is between an index with `ancestor: yes`, and one without, generally speaking.